# Run and Search appear in RCP Menubar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I suddenly have "Run" and "Search" in the menubar of my RCP application.  Is there anyway to remove them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, check **[this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg08462.html)** (and the article "[Contributing Actions to the Eclipse Workbench](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html)" used in [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=91951691)):

> The trick was "`check the launcher config`" -- even after a completely fresh install of Eclipse 3.1.1, with precisely nothing else in my WS except my own plugins, the annoying extra menus and annoying error "edit last position" were still present.
>
> Then I went to the launcher config as you suggested, which had loads of cruft (created automagically by Eclipse) -- **so I deselected all, selected my plugins, and clicked "`Add Required`"**; running from the WS with that -- great!

See also [bug 115998](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=115998)

> removing the "platform" feature fixes it all up -- a very simple fix that was very hard to find!

---

That said, in general, to hide some action contributions you can try, like in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg06131.html) to:

1/ to hide menu/coolbar defined by ActionSet Extension Point.

```
IWorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(actionSetId)
IWorkbenchPage.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.search.menu");
```

2/ Hide its menu:

```
MenuManager mbManager = ((ApplicationWindow)page.getWorkbenchWindow()).getMenuBarManager();
for (int i=0; i<mbManager.getItems().length; i++){
  IContributionItem item=mbManager.getItems()[i];
  if (item.getId().equals("org.eclipse.search.menu")){
    item.setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Or you can try [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg11029.html), to hide it for any perspective through a `PerspectiveListener`:

> The action ids I got from browsing through my dependent eclipse plugins.. searching for `ActionSets`

```
package ch.post.pf.gui.prototyp.sesam.pstonline;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveListener;
import org.eclipse.ui.IStartup;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

public class ActionWiper implements IStartup, IPerspectiveListener {

    private static final String[] ACTIONS_2_WIPE = new String[] {
            "org.eclipse.search.searchActionSet",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.presentation",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.openExternalFile",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation",
            "org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo",
            "org.eclipse.update.ui.softwareUpdates" };

    public void earlyStartup() {
        IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getWorkbenchWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
            IWorkbenchPage page = windows[i].getActivePage();
            if (page != null) {
                wipeActions(page);
            }
            windows[i].addPerspectiveListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void wipeActions(IWorkbenchPage page) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ACTIONS_2_WIPE.length; i++) {
            wipeAction(page, ACTIONS_2_WIPE[i]);
        }

    }

    private void wipeAction(final IWorkbenchPage page, final String actionsetId) {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                page.hideActionSet(actionsetId);
            }
        });
    }

    public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page,
            IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) {
        wipeActions(page);
    }

    public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page,
            IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) {
    }    
}
```

And remove the preferences:

> With the `PreferenceManager` I got even rid of the unwanted Preferences..:)
>   Where the `PREFERENCES_2_WIPE` Strings have to be the IDs of the main categories you want to get rid off. Like the
>   "org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.Workbench" -> shows up as General

```
PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPreferenceManager();
for (int i = 0; i < PREFERENCES_2_WIPE.length; i++) {
    pm.remove(PREFERENCES_2_WIPE[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It turns out all I had to do was select the "required plug-ins" in my run configurations plug-ins tab.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked (hope it helps you):

```
  <extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
 <activity
       id="someid.remove"
       name="RemoveSearchMenu">
    <enabledWhen>
       <with
             variable="activePartId">
          <equals
                value="someidr.RemoveSearchMenu1">
          </equals>
       </with></enabledWhen>
 </activity>
 <activityPatternBinding
       activityId="someid.remove"
       pattern="org.eclipse.search.*">
 </activityPatternBinding>
```